# Can we define auto increment attribute in core data?

Tags: iphone

Hello I am using core data in my application, and want to set ID attribute in every entity as autoincrement. Is it possible in core data? Or I have to manually insert the entry and manage the increment programatically??

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you are thinking of the id for the primary keys then core data handles this for you. On each object there is an `objectID` property you can access to see it. When you create an object from the managed object context, core data assigns a temporary id. When you commit the changes from the managed object context, core data assigns a perminant id. I don't think it would be a good idea to manually try and set this.

Read [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351998/creating-a-unique-id-for-a-core-data-program-on-the-iphone) for more details.

Comment: How to convert objectId into NSNumber so you can store it on core data?

Answer (score 3):

I used that way with `NSFetchedResultsController`:

first sorting:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: false)]
```

Then in add object method:

```
// Minimum id value
var recordID = 1
if let lastRecordID = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.first?.id {
    recordID = Int(lastRecordID) + 1
}

let newRecord = Record(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
newRecord.id = Int32(recordID)
```