# Is it safe to use NSManagedObject objectID: use as PK for record filtering, joining tables and etc?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, primary-key

Should I need to have explicit custom ID attribute as PK for each of my core data entities? I'm aware of the fact core data uses its own [objectID column for every entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351998/creating-a-unique-id-for-a-core-data-program-on-the-iphone/2126793#2126793) and we can grab it from [NSManagedObject objectID].

My previous projects were done using raw SQLite, but now I'm trying to move to core data. Currently in my core data prototype, I'm filtering records using my custom ID column:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"my_id=%d",some_id_value]];
```

Just curious, should I bother myself with custom ID attributes, or should I rely on internal objectID column: pass it here and there, use for filtering, joining tables and etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea behind coredata is to avoid low-level sql. As in every modern ORM you should not be bothered with internal object ids. At first this may seem a little awkward (especially if you come from a heavy sql background) but believe me it is a lot more easier to manage your object graph this way. So bottom line, design your NSManagedObjects and relationships and let coredata do its magic with all the ids.

Comment: While this is certainly a good reply to this specific request, there are a few specific circumstances in which you need to refer to Core Data objects by IDs: writing a sync engine, for example. Also, some of the ways of multithreading Core Data require you to pass object IDs between threads. That said, in general (for querying, fetching etc) you don't need to work with IDs.

Comment: @AmyWorrall Tottaly agree with you. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Thanks, but how should I filter an object by identifier? It's the most common thing: to grab concrete object(record) and to save concrete object (record). How would you suggest to replace my current code ( setPredicate, my_id)? Still, I do not understand how can I update, select and delete concrete object without having some identifier mapped to table id.

Comment: Is it absolutely crucial to you to filter the objects by their ids? Why don't you fetch them by predicates based on their properties (for example: `firstName like 'Mark'` or `grade == 7`). Also once you create a relationship between two entities you can use predicates on them also (example: `ALL children.age > 12` will fetch all the children over 12 years old, of the entity you execute the fetch request against (a Person entity for example), given that you have created a one-to-many relationship in Person named 'children').

Comment: Identifier is always an identifier and it's more convenient and lightweight to pass all around an app only one value/s and to update/delete using one value. Also, fetching records by ID is always faster than fetching by some two columns, because ID (PK) is always index based. Otherwise, you would need explicitly to create another index on other columns in order to make such query faster, and that would be redundant. I came from heavy database development  background and I can't see my life without ID's :)