# Auto Index for a CoreData in Objective-c

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, indexing

I have to generate a unique id for each of  my core data records, is there any way  to set  an auto incremental index in core data? Such us pure sqlite! If not, what could be the best strategy to manage this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a unique id for a Core Data program on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351998/creating-a-unique-id-for-a-core-data-program-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is NSManagedObjectID

```
NSManagedObjectID *moID = [managedObject objectID];
```

But why not just to search?
[Creating a unique id for a Core Data program on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351998/creating-a-unique-id-for-a-core-data-program-on-the-iphone)